# Trying to access ng-repeat object value in child directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular and I am trying to pass in the current object's key:value to a child directive. I tried interpolating the required value as an attribute in the child directive. Although present in the DOM,the attrs object in the child directive stores the attribute value as undefined. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

```
<reminder ng-repeat="reminder in reminders.delegatedReminders"></reminder>

.directive('reminder', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: 'true',
      template: '<li class="reminder-content" rel="{{reminder.traveler.conversationLink}}"><editwidget></editwidget><div>{{reminder.traveler.name}}</div><div>{{reminder.text}}</div><div>{{reminder.time}}</div></li>',
      link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
        elem.on('click',function(){
            var chatLink= attrs.rel;
            // console.log(val);
        });

        elem.on('mouseover',function(){

        });
      }
  };
}).directive('editwidget',function(){
return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:'true',
    template: '<div class="widget-container"><tick ng-attr-item="_id"></tick><cross></cross></div>'
}
})
.directive('tick',function(){
return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:false,
    scope:{
        _id:'@'
    },
    template: '<div>tick</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        attrs.$observe('id',function(value){
            console.log(value);
        })
    }
  }
```

})

i need to access the id field from the current object of ng-repeat and access that in the tick directive, so that i can get the value on click of the directive.
THanks in advance !

Comment: Can you please paste some code or create a fiddle?